# Strange red marking for style format in VS code 1.65.0

Tags: javascript, react-native, visual-studio-code

In my React Native 0.67.4 app, I just notice some red marking in some component's js file. The red marking is only about the style sheets. Here is an image of the red marking:

[image]

Here is the styles definition:

```
const styles = Style.create(
 ...
 centeredView: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginTop: 22
  },
  modalView: {
    margin: 30,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    borderRadius: 20,
    padding: 35,
    alignItems: "center",
    alignContent:"center",
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 2
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 4,
    elevation: 5
  },
)
```

The same red marking also appears for the format below:

```
<View style={styles.cneteredView, {fontSize:20}}>...</View>
```

Here is the `devDependency` in `package.json`:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
```

Is there a way to get rid of the red marking?

Comment: If you hover over that text what does VScode tell you it's warning you about? I'd recommend [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) if you're not using CSS-in-JS.

Comment: add an extra set of curly braces (`{}`) around those objects. e.g `<View style={{styles.centeredView, {fontSize: 20}}}>...</View>`

Comment: It means you have an error there. fix the error and see if it goes away.

Comment: yo if you want to use two styles of classes it is not how to use it that why the editor is showing you error correct way to use it is like this
`style={[styles.red, styles.big]}`

Comment: hover shows "JSX may not use comma. Did you mean an array", Double {} doesn't work.

Comment: `[]` makes the red marking disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yoo if you want to use two styles of classes or styling it is not how you use it that is why the editor is showing you error correct way to use it is like this

```
style={[styles.red, styles.big]}
style={[styles.cneteredView, {fontSize:20}]}
```